When was the first instance of the military synchronizing watches?
What was the first military instance of officers synchronizing their watches (time pieces?) prior to military action.
I was recently watching a movie, "The Crossing" where General Washington acting on the first intelligence of the Culpeper Spy ring, crossed the Delaware River and attacked Hessian mercenary troops at Trenton New Jersey.  Prior to "The Crossing" General Washington had his officers synchronize their watches to his in what has been claimed in several places including the movie to be the first such occurrence before a battle.

Every Soldier would carry three days of rations and forty rounds of ammunition, while all officers set their watches by Washington’s to ensure synchronized execution of this raid.
The National Museum of the United States Army

Now I know from previous readings Washington was a collector of watches often traveling into town to set his watches.  He did so as a delegate to the declaration of Indepenence and also later in life as a gentleman farmer.  Also the first mass-produced military wristwatch is generally considered to be the Girard-Perregaux wristwatch ordered by German Emperor Wilhelm I in the 1880s, 100 years after Washington's famous crossing.  Pocket watches had been around since 1510:

The first pocket watch was invented by a German watchmaker named Peter Henlein in 1510.

So while they were available during Washington's time they would have been very expensive and a luxury item.
Does anybody know of an earlier example of synchronization of watches before a military battle than Dec 26th, 1776?  Also, how many of Washington's officers likely even had watches, certainly not most of them.
I was thinking of John Harrison, the British inventor of the Marine Timepiece who entered a contest, the 1714 Longitude Act, to produce a reliable way to calculate Longitude at sea.  His solution relied on the first reliable time piece for naval officers which he invented.  His final time piece, came out in the mid 1770s was a pocket watch and was set by astronomical readings for navigation.

Harrison's time pieces were used for astronomicas readings for navigation at sea.  NOT astrological readings.  ASTRONOMICAL not ASTROLOGICAL.   The Hessians were not mercenaries.  They were professional soldiers of the Landgravate of Hesse-Cassel, serving as allies of the British forces. If anyone was a mercenary it was the Landgrave himself..

@MAGolding You can argue the mercenary point today, but contemporarily, they were definitely considered thus, as the 25th of the 27 Grievances in the Declaration of Independence proves: "He is at this time transporting large Armies of foreign Mercenaries..." They were hired auxiliaries. The distinction wears pretty thin there. ;-)

This article from Weapons and Warfare suggests that adoption of mechanical timekeeping as a military technology was pretty slow. It seems likely to me that the example mentioned in the question is the first of its kind... but how to prove that?

One probably cannot give a precise answer, but probably this happened when pocket watches came into  common use, that is in the 18 century. And probably in the navy: naval operations may frequently require synchronization.

@Alex How so? A single ship will be under the command of one person, so no need to synchronize. Multiple ships move so slowly that coordination is more a question of wind. I don't see any application in the 18th century where ship clocks differing by 5 or 10 minutes would make any difference.

@quarague: Ships sometimes interact in fleets, and also perform landing operations when a boat landing party interacts with the ship crew, sometimes separated by large distance. These operations are sometimes performed at night, when direct communication by visual signals is difficult.
